# Cannot connect to MemSQL through SQLApi++

Tags: c++, mysql, database, singlestore, sqlapi++

I'm trying to connect to `MemSQL` database from `c++` code and I'm using `SQLApi++` library. `MySQL` client is compatible with `MemSQL` and `SQLApi++` has support of `MySQL`. However I can't connect and get different errors.

For example, I'm calling connect with the following parameters

```
Connect("tcp://localhost:3307", "root", "", SA_MySQL_Client)
```

and get an error saying `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.

I have searched on the internet and tried several versions of specifying DB hostname, however non of them have worked. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct version? Any Ideas?

NOTE: I can successfully connect to `MemSQL` with command-line by just executing
`memsql -P 3307`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I provided local IP address and port, for some reason `SQLApi++` ignored it and always tried to connect to `MySQL`'s socket in default path (i.e. `/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`).

However, after reading [documentation](http://www.sqlapi.com/ServerSpecific/MySQL.html#Connecting%20to%20a%20database) once more, it turned out that it is possible to pass socket's path as a host name. So I passed `MemSQL`'s socket path and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MySQL installed on the same machine as MemSQL?  localhost can redirect to MySQL in some clients, but 127.0.0.1 won't (see https://docs.memsql.com/v5.7/docs/how-to-connect-to-memsql)

Does Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", "SA_MySQL_Client") work?

Comment: Yes, I have `MySQL` installed. I have tried with IP, but it gives the same error.

Comment: I have also updated my question. I can connect from command-line, but I cannot from `c++` code.

Comment: Looking at the docs for SqlAPI++ I think the last param is an enum and your passing it as a string. 

Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3307", "root", "", SA_MySQL_Client)

Comment: Actually I use `SA_MySQL_Client` without quotes, it was just a typo in my port. However, I have found that it tried to connect to `MySQL` no matter what I write...

Comment: Moreover, it turned out that `SQLApi++` uses `libmysqlclient`, are there any extra steps for connecting to `MemSQL` via that lib? Or just providing corresponding host and port should be enough?

Comment: using 127.0.0.1 for host and 3307 for port should work.  I've never used sqlapi++, but the docs seems to say the host string should be "host,port".  Maybe try that syntax instead of :port?

Comment: After reading documentation once more, it turned out that it is possible to pass socket's path as a host name. That one worked!

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and nabroyan has already mentioned one solution. Just providing some details on it and adding another possible solution as well.

Seems like when SQLAPI figures out that the server is running on local host, then it goes directly to the socket file, and unfortunately it always goes to the MySQL's socket file i.e. /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

Now there can be two possible solutions here:

**1- Update your MemSQL instance to use the same socket file as that of MySQL (it may only be a choice if you are not running MySQL as well on that same box)**

(haven't tested it myself, so maybe missing some steps here) You can probably do this by updating the value of "socket" in memsql.cnf file, so it should look like:

`socket = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`

You can find the location of memsql.cnf file using the command that is used to figure out the socket file location, memsql.cnf file will be in the same directory:

```
memsql -u root --password=YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE -P 3306 -e "show variables like 'socket'"
```

Once done, you should restart the memsql:

```
memsql-ops memsql-restart
```

---

**2- OR Modify your connection string to provide the MemSQL socket path.**

You can figure out memsql socket file using the command mentioned under first option.

In my case the file was : /app/memsql/master-3306-NJG846fb0e/data/memsql.sock
so I modified my connection call to use this file:

```
Connect("/app/memsql/master-3306-NJG846fb0e/data/memsql.sock@", "myuser", "mypassword", SA_MySQL_Client);
```